# MySQL AS keyword

Tags: mysql

I'm not professional in query writing, but wrote many from the time I began MySQL. Recently I noticed there is no need to type `AS` keyword in name aliasing.

```
SELECT name AS n
```

equals to

```
SELECT name n
```

However I know that this ability is out from years ago. I've 2 questions around this subject:

1. Is `AS` keyword redundant?
2. Sometimes ago when I encountered with a custom query on a website with having no `AS` in aliasing, that its executing made MySQL service down, I changed the way of name aliasing with adding `AS` keyword and this little change made it work!

   What was the problem here?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454951/why-would-you-use-as-when-aliasing-a-sql-table - aliasing column names is syntactic sugar that makes the query a little bit easier to read.

Comment: Probably you used a version of mysql that demanded the as keyword.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner and also is its both use documented officially?

Comment: I asked 2 question, for the sake of second one why close votes?

Comment: @revo It doesn't make any sense for the MySQL service to shutdown when there is a syntactical error in a query. Btw, there is not even a syntactical error because `AS` is NOT required.

Comment: @MostyMostacho I didn't say mysql service had shut down. I said service went down, but still I needed to restart it to make it available. Also it wasn't about syntactical error because mysql didn't throw an error.

Comment: You should address your second question to the `service` provider.

Comment: @revo: I really can't explain what you experienced in your second question. Possibly there was *already* problem with the service that was only noticed when your an the query. I'd have to *see* and *reproduce for myself* something like that to believe it and explain it (mind you, I haven't used MySQL for a long time - a MySQL guru might know this one).

Answer (score 24):

For the answer to 1), the mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html:

> A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`,
>   `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) AS full_name   FROM mytable
> ORDER BY full_name;
> ```
>
> The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an
>   identifier. The preceding example could have been written like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name) full_name   FROM mytable
> ORDER BY full_name;
> ```
>
> However, because the AS is optional, a subtle problem can occur if you
>   forget the comma between two select_expr expressions: MySQL interprets
>   the second as an alias name. For example, in the following statement,
>   columnb is treated as an alias name:
>
> ```
> SELECT columna columnb FROM mytable;
> ```
>
> For this reason, it is good practice to be in the habit of using AS
>   explicitly when specifying column aliases.
>
> It is not permissible to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause,
>   because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE
>   clause is executed. See Section C.5.5.4, “Problems with Column
>   Aliases”.

This also very similar syntactically for tables:

> A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or
>   tbl_name alias_name:
>
> ```
> SELECT t1.name, t2.salary FROM employee AS t1, info AS t2   WHERE
> t1.name = t2.name;
>
> SELECT t1.name, t2.salary FROM employee t1, info t2   WHERE t1.name =
> t2.name;
> ```

For the Answer to 2) I don't think there is anyway you can tell without a full description of the software versions, query being run and error messages received.

Comment: aliasing in my case was about table names and there were no error in executing query. but a good answer.