# MySQL: Combine 3 queries into one

Tags: mysql

I have 3 queries that collect statistic:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(id) count,
  DATE(created_at) date
FROM t1
GROUP BY
  date;

SELECT
  COUNT(id) count,
  DATE(created_at) date
FROM t2
GROUP BY
  date;

SELECT
  COUNT(id) count,
  DATE(date_started) date
FROM t1
GROUP BY
  date;
```

Right now I run these queries 3 separate times to get those data. 
Is it possible to combine these into 1 query to get something like this?

```
date       | count1 | count2 | count3
-------------------------------------
2018-04-25 | 5      | (null) | 2
2018-04-24 | (null) | 3      | 4
```

Comment: you can do it with the use of union to consolidate data and then pivot them from vertically to horizontly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT
  `date`,
  SUM(count1) count1,
  SUM(count2) count2,
  SUM(count3) count3
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DATE(created_at) `date`,
      COUNT(id) count1,
      NULL count2,
      NULL count3
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY DATE(created_at)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      DATE(created_at) `date`,
      NULL count1,
      COUNT(id) count2,
      NULL count3
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY DATE(created_at)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      DATE(date_started) `date`,
      NULL count1,
      NULL count2,
      COUNT(id) count3
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY DATE(date_started)
  ) q
GROUP BY `date`
```

SQL Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcfb9e/1

Comment: I tried this and `count1` has numbers while the other `count2`,`count3` all have null value...

Comment: Sorry, the order of the selects wasn't in the same order as yours, and I thought the order isn't important after I changed it as you have it works. Seems like select order IS important.

Comment: OK. I've changed my answer and added SQL Fiddle test.

Comment: Yes, the order of subqueries' columns is important when you use `UNION ALL`. But the order of subqueries isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).
Just take the date as join column and use an outer join in order to get the `null` values where no combinations are found. Then rename the colums in the `select` part.

If you have problems with the group, you can use [subquerys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) in MySQL as well.

You can also use the `as` [keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567732/mysql-as-keyword) in order to have a better overview with your tables.

Of course it would be great to optimize your query when there are many tuples in the tables.