# MySQL query two tables in one statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called, group, and another table called member.
group has fields of groupId, name, etc...
member has fields of memberId, groupId, memberName, etc... where groupId is being a foreign key to group table.
I want to query these two table in a single statement such that the result outputs as follows.

```
[
  {
    "groupId": "8",
    "name": "Test Group 2",
    "status": "0",
    "member": [
      {
        "memberId": "1",
        "groupId": "8",
        "memberName": "tester 1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have looked into INNER JOIN and UNION but couldn't figure out how to achieve this.
Any advice would be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM group INNER JOIN member
ON group.groupId = member.groupId`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725556/how-can-i-merge-two-mysql-tables

Comment: @pc_ This question indeed looks like something that already has an answer. But the mentioned duplicate does not seem to fit in the scope of this question IMO.

Comment: @Koen Hollander Thanks, looks to me that both issues are almost identicall, I myself could work out the answer on the one I pointed from answers there.

Comment: @pc_ I see, they indeed look the same, maybe the scope of the questions does not fit, but the answers does. Thanks! (But still, I don't think that the mentioned question will solve this question also. But, that's my opinion ;) )

Comment: @Koen Hollander thumbs up for checking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with 2 queries, array column, and array map.

First query, get all the needed groups, and fetch it into a variable e.g `$groups`

```
SELECT group_id, name, status FROM groups
```

And then get all group_id from the `$groups`.

```
$groupIds = implode(',', array_column($groups, 'group_id'));
```

You will get list of `group_id` as a string separated with comma. And then use it in second query:

```
"SELECT member_id, group_id, member_name FROM member WHERE group_id IN (" . $groupIds . ")"
```

Fetch the result in `$members`. And the final task is to combine the result.

```
foreach ($groups as $key => $group) {
    $groupMember = array_filter($members, function($member) use ($group) {
        return $group['group_id'] == $member['group_id'];
    });
    $group['member'] = $groupMember; // I don't know if this works
    $groups[$key] = $groupMember; // if previous line doesn't work
}
```

---

**P.S**
This will be a lot easier if you use PHP Framework like Laravel. It has [eloquent one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and [eager load `with` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)  which you can achieve same result with just:

```
Group::with("member")->get();
```

I don't know other framework, I'm sure there are other frameworks that are able to do this too.

Comment: This works. Since I wanted to have a member array within every each group, I ended up doing what you wrote. I guess this is not possible to do by one query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM group 
    INNER JOIN member ON group.groupId = member.groupId
```

but the result is as

```
    [
      {
        "groupId": "8",
        "name": "Test Group 2",
        "status": "0",
        "memberId": "1",
         "groupId": "8",
        "memberName": "tester 1"

      }
    ]
```

a row for each join between master and detail rows

SQL query return tabular result and not nested  result

Answer (score 0):

Your question is broad, but maybe this will help you

```
SELECT user.memberName, group.name
FROM user 
INNER JOIN group ON group.groupId = user.groupId
```

Not tested, but this will select the group name and username from the tables with an `INNER JOIN`

You can also select other columns, but be sure that they don't have the same name. Otherwise the select will fail. (You can work that around by using the `as` keyword [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567732/mysql-as-keyword))