# How can I rewrite this query by not having AS?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm completing a HackerRank challenge, but the documentation says I should not use the `AS` keyword:

[image]

I need to rewrite this query in MySQL so it doesn't include the `AS` in `WITH A AS`, nor `AS in SELECT...AS test`

```sql
WITH A AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MAX( LENGTH( customer_id ) ) AS test
    FROM
        orders

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT
        MIN( LENGTH( customer_id ) )
    FROM
        orders
)
SELECT
    test,
    LENGTH(test)
FROM
    A
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567732/mysql-as-keyword

Comment: Why? It makes queries more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Using `SELECT DISTINCT` with `MAX(...)` or `MIN()` without a `GROUP BY` is redundant because those inner-queries will only return 1 row.

Comment: Ty JoSSte. Dai, I'm doing problems on hackerrank and they ask you don't include AS in queries as it will give bad results.

Comment: Also, `LENGTH()` is for strings, but `test` is an `int`...

Comment: @Klein Please share a link or screenshot of the message from HackerRank - I'm skeptical that they'd say that...

Comment: @Dai  [link](https://imgur.com/a/vybtY0Q)

Comment: @Klein Wow, that's _really janky_. You should contact them about that...

Comment: It's true that _in Oracle SQL_ they disallow `AS` for defining a table alias for no good reason — they just never got around to implementing that syntax _in 40 years._ But it's standard SQL syntax, and in other implementations it is allowed. This sounds like hackerrank are ignorant of standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WITH clause is using for declare a VIEW, so you can rewrite it like below

```
SELECT
    test,
    LENGTH(test)
FROM
    (
 SELECT DISTINCT
        MAX( LENGTH( customer_id ) ) AS test
    FROM
        orders

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT
        MIN( LENGTH( customer_id ) )
    FROM
        orders)
```

Comment: "The `WITH` clause is using for declare a `VIEW`" <-- That's nonsense. `WITH` is for CTEs and has nothing special to do with `VIEW` objects.

Comment: ofc this is not VIEW object.. I mean view as queries reusable or named query

Comment: The correct term for that is a [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), not a "reusable query" or "named query".

Comment: Yes, the correct term is CTE but it is used for  e.g. better code readability, so yes for reusable query

Comment: The ANSI/ISO SQL standard term is actually `WITH`, (optional) Feature T121.

Comment: @jarlh My copy of the SQL-1999 spec refers to them as `COMMON_TABLE` expressions (part 2, page 253).

Comment: @Dai, interesting, I didn't know that. However, COMMON_TABLE can't be be found in SQL-2003, SQL-2008, SQL-2011 or SQL-2016. No idea why it was changed.

Comment: @jarlh Looking at the SQL-2011 spec now, the term for `COMMON_TABLE` now [seems to be "`table subquery`"](https://imgur.com/a/cD5FcH5) - I'm hesistant to refer to the subquery itself as a "`WITH` query" though.