# Can I use mysql alises withoud the "as" keyword

Tags: mysql

So my question is, does the following have any differrences?

```
select count(students) as nos from tbl_student;
```

or

```
select count(students)nos from tbl_student
```

Comment: No there are nor differences

Comment: There is no difference in both expression Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164653/whats-the-purpose-of-sql-keyword-as

Comment: AS is optional. But the difference between two queries is ... you don't even have a white space in your seconds query before nos. That will give you an error :-p

Comment: @riz you're mistaken. These queries are identical, as EXPLAIN EXTENDED would demonstrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. 'AS' keyword is optional.

People find it more readable and clear while you use AS keyword. The reason for using it is that when reading a large query, it is easier to pick out the aliases by looking for the AS's.

Follow this [SO QUESTION1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454951/why-would-you-use-as-when-aliasing-a-sql-table)... [SO QUESTION2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567732/mysql-as-keyword)... [SO QUESTION3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164653/whats-the-purpose-of-sql-keyword-as)

Comment: This is opinion, and not one I share.

Comment: Definitely makes it easier to skim large queries