# Can "AS" be skipped in MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

Instead of `table1 AS t1`, can I write `table1 t1` ?

So, is `JOIN table1 t1 on table2.userid = t1.userid`?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. The answer is yes. But you can try it and after ask the question. maybe dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454951/why-would-you-use-as-when-aliasing-a-sql-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL AS keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567732/mysql-as-keyword)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You could have looked that up yourself.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

> tbl_name [[AS] alias] [index_hint]