# Show MySQL row content on PHP from specific table column (same .row name on different tables)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my app, I have **two tables** that contain **two columns** with the **same column name**

Table TITLES

```
COLUMN = name    - CONTENT example: Jurassic World Trailer
```

Table VIDEOS

```
COLUMN = name    - CONTENT example:<img src='/abc.png'>
```

I need to display rows from both columns "name" in my PHP file, but the row="name" from TITLES table always comes first, and I cant dispaly the image from the VIDEOS row="name".

```
        // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      

            $written_fichas = $written_fichas .' target="_parent">'.$row['name'].'</a></b></div></td></tr><tr><td align="right"><div class="44"> '.$row["name"];
```

It is clear that I must change the way in which the second query is extracted for the table "videos" and add besides $row['name'] **and the name of the table**, but how should I do this?

```
<div class="44"> '$VIDEOS-TABLE->.$row["name"];
```

**Expected result for the code above**

```
target="_parent">Jurassic World Trailer</a> //name come from titles table and is OK
</b></div></td></tr><tr><td align="right">
<div class="44"><img src='/abc.png'> //name NEED to come from VIDEOS table
```

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE - more code.

```
// First query
$sql = "SELECT MAX(l.`id`) FROM `videos` as l WHERE l.approved = 1" . $type2 ." GROUP BY l.`title_id`,  l.`name`, l.`season`, l.`episode` ORDER BY l.`id` DESC LIMIT 1000";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    $ids_max=[];
    while($row = $result->fetch_row())
        $ids_max[]=$row[0];
    $where_in = implode(',', $ids_max); 

    // Second query: 
    $sql = "SELECT l.id, l.name, l.title_id, t.name, t.poster, l.season, l.episode, l.approved FROM `videos` as l, `titles` as t WHERE l.title_id = t.id AND l.`id` IN (" .$where_in .")" .$type ." ORDER BY l.`id` DESC LIMIT " .$offset .", " .$limit;
    //print $sql;
    $result = $last_id = $conn->query($sql);

    //write head
    $file = fopen($filename, "w");
    $written_head = "
        <head>
        <link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/styles.css\"> 
        </head>
        <body>
    fwrite($file, $written_head . PHP_EOL);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
            if (empty($row['episode'])) {
                $written_fichas = "<div><table><tr><td><a href=/".$row['title_id'].'-'.$row['name'];
                $written_fichas = $written_fichas .' target="_parent"><img src='.$row['poster'].' /></a><div>&nbsp;</div></td>';
                $written_fichas = $written_fichas ."</tr><tr><td><table><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td><div class='55'><b><a href=/".$row['title_id'];
                $written_fichas = $written_fichas .' target="_parent">'.$row['name'].'</a></b></div></td></tr><tr><td><div class="44"> '.$row["name"];
                $written_fichas = $written_fichas .'</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>';

            fwrite($file, $written_fichas . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }else {
        fwrite($file, "0 results". PHP_EOL);}
```

Comment: `print_r($row)`, also show your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax in MySql:

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name FROM table_name;

SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name AS alias_name;
```

[Why would you use "AS" when aliasing a SQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454951/why-would-you-use-as-when-aliasing-a-sql-table)

The following code is a solution for you:

Update second query to this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT l.id, l.name as video_name, l.title_id, t.name, t.poster, l.season, l.episode, l.approved FROM `videos` as l, `titles` as t WHERE l.title_id = t.id AND l.`id` IN (" .$where_in .")" .$type ." ORDER BY l.`id` DESC LIMIT " .$offset .", " .$limit;
```

Update last line to this one:

```
<div class="44"> '.$row["video_name"];
```

Comment: I have update the post - the problem is on the last lines of the code - <div class="44"> '.$row["name"]; - all others $row["name"] are OK, and come from TITLES table, but the last, need to come from VIDEOS table - you can rewrite this code for me??? - Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer and I add a solution for you. @ivan